# Respond to split-screen changes in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, split-screen-multitasking

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I have a MasterDetailPage with MasterBehavior set to Split when the device Idiom is Tablet. That is, I always want master page to be displayed.

The exception is during multitasking. For example, on iOS, if the user enters Split View, then I want the app to behave like it's on a phone, with no split view, but instead just a master or detail page displayed, and the proper navigation controls to move between them.

It seems like MasterDetailPage wants to help me with this. When I drag up another app to enter Split View on iOS, my app no longer shows the master page. However, the detail page that remains has no navigation control to return to the master.

What is the proper way to detect the mode change and dynamically adjust the navigation in Xamarin.Forms when your app enters and leaves Split View on iOS or split-screen mode on Android?